# Angular how can I retrieve from authguard?

Tags: angular, post, angular-http-interceptors, jwt, auth-guard

I have an Angular-springboot program with jwt authentication, I would like to know how I can once logged in on angular, recover the data of who logged in, for example the username. I looked at some guides on authguard and httpinterceptors but I am a bit confused in rigurado, can any of you please post me a code in which it retrieves data? I have services copied from the guides which are auth-guard, authentication, basic-auth-http-interceptors and httpclient I think are pretty standard but if needed I will publish them

Comment: Hello,

First off, some of the services you listed aren't really used for retrieving/getting data. For example:

- Authguard: If you're referring to a RouteGuard, these are used to allow/block the user from accessing a particular route, which is commonly based on authentication (https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)
- HttpInterceptors: These are used to perform any additional logic for whichever API requests you want to target (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

What do you do with the authenticated user's details once they log in? (like their id)

Comment: **TYPO** alert - it's a **guard** - not a "gaurd" ....

Answer (score 0):

When user log in to the system save the token type and jwt token in the local storage. With the help of TokenInterceptor it sends header details in every request.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('token_type')} ${localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

In app.module.ts add provider `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }`

Answer (score 0):

thank you, yes i have an interceptor like this that save in the local storage, but if i am in another component, and i want call this, for example i press a button and, in the method i want do for example, a post that if you press this button you have to be logged ok?, and you have to update db, so i need to know who pressed this, how can retrieve this?